# Problems in setting up my own Stanford CoreNLP server:

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server, corenlp-server

I'm setting up my own stanford parser server following the tutorial in http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html. However, when I paste the example code, it comes out an error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Could not connect to server: localhost:9000
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPClient$2.run(StanfordCoreNLPClient.java:393)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPClient$2.run(StanfordCoreNLPClient.java:374)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPClient;

public class tagger {
    public static void test(){
        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");

        StanfordCoreNLPClient pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLPClient(props, "localhost", 9000, 2);
        // read some text in the text variable
        String text = "How are you today?";
        // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you give works unaltered for me. (It doesn't print anything; you might try putting something like `System.out.println(document.toShorterString());` at the end of `test()` while testing it, but it works....)

Did you start the server and leave it running using the first instruction here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#getting-started ? This just looks like the server isn't running on port 9000 of your local machine.